# How to print key Value in Excel sheet using Apache Poi

Tags: java

I am currently exporting the data present in a hash map to excel sheet using Apache POI.

I am able to successfully print all the values that the map has, but not the key values.

Can someone tell me on how we can print the key value as well as a second column in excel sheet.

Comment: Could you please post your code, so we can help you

Comment: Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.

Comment: Pleas eadd your code to the body of the question.  That way it will be readable.  Welcome to the site, but I strongly encourage you to read the FAQ for tips about how to interact here.  It will make for a more successful experience for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by your question, but from what i can tell to get the keys from the hash map you would use .keyset() to get the Set of Strings for the HashMap, and just iterate through those. From what little experience i have with apache poi, i believe it operates on rows, so you can use createRow or getRow, and you can test whether or not it exists by seeing if it is null. Same goes for the columns createCell or getCell (something like that) and just test whether or not its null to get the boundaries, if its not null and you used the get method, then you should be able to read the value from that object. I hope that this helps.

Comment: LinkedHashMap IncompleteValues=new LinkedHashMap();
Set<Entry> entries=IncompleteValues.entryset();
int rownum=1;
for(Entry ent:entries)
{
Row row=sheet.createRow(rownum);
ArrayList objArr=(ArrayList)IncompleteValues.get(key);
int cellnum=0;
for(Object obj:objArr)
{
Cell cell=row.createCell(cellnum++);
if(obj instance of String)
cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
rownum++;
}
}

Comment: with the above code i am able to successfully print all the values to excel sheet that are associated with each key but not the key value.